# Consensus Forecast Data for NFP

Tags: forecasting

Does anybody know where I can get historical consensus forecast data for Non-forma Payroll (NFP)?

Or any forecast data for NFP.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on http://www.forexfactory.com/.

Click details on "Non-Farm Employment Change" and you will have consensus and actual data for last 15+ years.

Comment: Thanks KarolisR, do ou know where I could get more detailed forecast consensus data such as the range or even the data itself.

Comment: I only know that source out of the ones that are free, sorry. You can get more detailed data on Bloomberg terminal if you have access to it.